# Polymorphic Associaton transaction fails in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations

I am unable to get my association to save in `localhost:3000/controller_name/new`. I believe it is due to `belongs_to` [failing validation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/870), but I am not sure how to fix it (beyond just dropping the association via [`requires:false`/`optional: true`](http://blog.michelada.io/whats-new-in-rails-5), the consequences of which I am not sure of). I created my association following this [tutorial](https://kconrails.com/2010/10/19/common-addresses-using-polymorphism-and-nested-attributes-in-rails/) but it was for a previous version of rails.

I have a polymorphic address table that can belong to events, businesses, users, etc. I am trying to add it to event.

Address migration - you can see it references `addressable`:

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :addresses do |t|     
      t.string :address

      t.decimal :latitude,  null: false, precision: 10, scale: 6, index: true
      t.decimal :longitude, null: false, precision: 10, scale: 6, index: true

      t.references :addressable, polymorphic: true, index: true 
    end
  end
end
```

Address model:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Event model:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :address, as: :addressable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

Event Controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  #...stuff...

  # GET /events/new
  def new
    @event = Event.new
    @event.address = @event.build_address
    #@event.address = Address.new(addressable: @event)
    #@event.address = @event.create_address
    #@event.address =  @addressable.User.new
  end

  #...stuff...
```

You can see I tried multiple methods to create the event's address, they mostly create the below item, the ones using `addressable` cause a `Nil` crash.

```
#<Address id: nil, address: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, addressable_type: "Event", addressable_id: nil>
```

Event Form (Uses Simple_form gem):

```
<%= simple_form_for @event do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :description %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :address do |address| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/address/form', :locals => {:f => address} %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Address form partial:

```
<!-- Google Maps Must be loaded -->
<% content_for :head do %>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCMh8-5D3mJSXspmJrhSTtt0ToGiA-JLBc&libraries=places"></script>
<% end %>

<div id="map"></div>

<%= f.input :address %>
<%= f.input :latitude %>
<%= f.input :longitude %>
```

Forms render fine. When I try to save I get

```
Started POST "/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-01 16:06:23 -0400
Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"R0zlSs3UUNV3x8sQn5ocmE4jP12uOsFza7FezBAuhP4sw2MhF1OhixF8sAfDsLpfMEX7x5rhJ9HZfbKna8ncEA==", "event"=>{"name"=>"asd", "description"
=>"asd", "address_attributes"=>{"address"=>"asd", "latitude"=>"1", "longitude"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Create Event"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

And I am kept on the `new` page. If I insert a `byebug` into `create` and print out `@event.errors` it shows:

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fb29c34a9a8 @base=#<Event id: nil, name: "asd", description: "asd", min_users: nil, max_users: nil, start_time: nil, recurring: nil, created_at: nil, upd
ated_at: nil>, @messages={:"address.addressable"=>["must exist"]}, @details={:"address.addressable"=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
```

How can I create the address.addressable? What are the consequences of turning off the requires validation as some SO answers suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the issues and wrote a [blog post](http://jarlowrey.com/blog/polymorphic-rails-5.html) discussing this in depth. Essentially I was encountering 2 separate problems

1.The error I was receiving - `"address.addressable"=>["must exist"]`. address.addressable is the 'parent' table's tuple ID. In my case it is the Event ID. This error is trying to tell me that this foreign key is missing from the new address when we try to save it in the controller's create function. Like I said in the question, you can set `optional:true` to ignore this problem, and it somehow magically gets filled in after saving the Event. Or you can manually assign it in the create function before it saves.

```
def create
  @event = Event.new(event_params)
  @event.address.addressable = @event #<<<<<<<<<<< manually assign address.addressable
  respond_to do |format|
    if @event.save #Saves the event. Addressable has something to reference now, but validation does not know this in time
      format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
    else
      #dont forget to remove the 'byebug' that was here
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

2.Event ID was a string. In my address migration I was using `t.references :addressable, polymorphic: true, index: true` which is an alias for and `addressable_id` of integer type. I needed to change my migration to use string IDs - so  delete the `references` line and add this in instead.

```
t.string :addressable_id, index: true
t.string :addressable_type, index: true
```

This is covered in slightly more detail in the blog post.

Answer (score 1):

run rake db:schema:dump, and then check file inside db/schema.rb, make sure you have 2 fields as follow 
* t.integer :addressable_id, 
* t.string  :addressable_type
and for more detail here is link about [Activerecord Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), if you have problem with your schema,  then you can run migration as follow

```
t.references :addressable, polymorphic: true, index: true
```

as event has many address through polymorphic association, you can use [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) to create the address
and below is sample code

```
@address = @event.addresses.build(attributes = {}, ...)
```

you may use @address not @event.address

Comment: I haven't been able to test it out yet, but I know that the address does have the addressable type and I'd in it. I included the output of using `@event.build_address` in the original text. I think the issue is that this leaves the Id empty?

Comment: if you already set the connection, for example has_one or has_many when you use @event.addresses.build (rails provided method) it will take care the id automatically, you don't have to insert / type it manually

Comment: I'm getting `undefined method 'build' for nil:NilClass` when I try `    @address = @event.address.build` in the `new` function of the event controller. And `undefined method 'addresses' for #<Event:0x007f3f288c0820> Did you mean? address address=` for `@event.address.build`. `@event.build_address` works but has these properties when passed to my form `{"id"=>nil, "address"=>nil, "latitude"=>nil, "longitude"=>nil, "addressable_type"=>"Event", "addressable_id"=>nil}`. IDK why the id isn't there.

Comment: you must create @ event using create! not new, so previous command @ event = Event.create!(event_params....) with this way your @event will be created first and has an id see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working either `Validation failed: Address addressable must exist` when using `create!` in the controller's `create` method. Using `create` causes the rollbacks in the same way as `new`.

Comment: it happened to me before then you have to trace out what makes validation failed, I believed you have some validation rule inside event model, then you should trace the logic, to make create not failed, that the one that I did